# Can I disable users present in Azure B2C instance in advance?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on a project that provisions users into Azure B2C via Azure Graph API call and we got a requirement to disable the users if they are terminated from company. The Termination Date can be anything (Past/Present/Future). If I know the termination date, Can I disable that particular user from B2C instance using the termination date?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you mean by "disable":

1. You can DELETE a B2C principal at any time.
2. You can also delete a B2C principal at a pre-determined time.  For example, by running a script that invokes an Azure Graph API call.
3. Alternatively, you can retain the principal, but block signin.  There are several ways to do this.  For example:

> [MSDN: Disable user sign-ins for an enterprise app in Azure Active
>   Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/disable-user-sign-in-portal)
>
> Powershell script:
>
> ```
> # The AppId of the app to be disabled
> $appId = "{AppId}"
>
> # Check if a service principal already exists for the app
> $servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
> if ($servicePrincipal) {
>     # Service principal exists already, disable it
>     Set-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -AccountEnabled $false
> } else {
>     # Service principal does not yet exist, create it and disable it at the same time
>     $servicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $appId -AccountEnabled $false
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand @paulms4 answer:

You can disable the user by setting:

"accountEnabled": false,